# How much to use the netty pipeline

Tags: java, netty

Currently I am implementing a simple Http Server using netty. I'm wondering how much to utilize the pipeline. For example should I do authentication in the pipeline? Should I determine where to route a request in the pipeline?

I know it's not effective to change the structure of the pipeline, but what are the advantages of spreading out the processing?

Answer (score 0):

Inbound messages are processed in network threads and any additional activities will block receiving and sending other messages by this channel.
Likely it is reasonable to left deserialization only in the pipeline and do other tasks in separate application threads.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of implementing your server with multiple modularized `ChannelHandler`s is that it encourages the separation of concerns. Although longer pipeline will yield more overhead, you should take into account that it's really a matter of trade-off.  Also, even if the runtime manipulation of pipeline configruation might be expensive, it shouldn't be very expensive as long as you have to manipulate the pipeline very often.